# Can the knockout throttle extender be changed after creation?

Tags: knockout.js, throttling

I would like my throttle as a dynamic number that I can change at will, however it doesn't seem possible. Is this a limitation of the throttle extender?

In my case I have a grid filter that I'm throttling. If I have only a few items in the grid, I would like a very low throttle. However if the grid row count gets very large I would like to change it (perhaps to a max of ~300ms). e.g.:

```
this.filter = ko.observable("").extend({ throttle: 1 });
```

then later I would like to do something like:

```
this.filter.extend.throttle = 300;
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a limitation of the throttle extender, but a limitation to how observable extensions work.  Perhaps you can make a new throttle extension that can inspect the observable and adjust the time accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That won't work for the built-in throttle method.

It's not hard to build this yourself. For example, here's some code that will allow you to call .throttle on any observable, passing an a throttle time observable which can be changed at will:

```
ko.subscribable.fn.throttle = function(throttleTimeObservable) {
    var subscribable = this;
    var throttledObservable = ko.observable();
    var timeoutHandle = null;

    if (ko.isObservable(throttleTimeObservable)) {
       throttletimeObservable.subscribe(function() { clearTimeout(timeoutHandle) });
    }

    subscribable.subscribe(function(val) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
        throttleTime = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(throttleTimeObservable);
        timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function() { throttledObservable(val); }, throttleTime);
    });

    return throttledObservable;
}
```

Using it is simple:

```
// Usage:
var existingObservable = ...;
var throttleTime = ko.observable(500);
var throttled = existingObservable.throttle(throttleTime);

// Change the throttle willy nilly!
throttleTime(1000);
```

If you're doing lots of stuff like this (throttling, composing different observables together), you might be interested in [Rx.js](http://reactive-extensions.github.com/RxJS/).